# Ng-idle in angular 6 is getting paused when system goes to sleep

Tags: angular, ng-idle

I have used Ng Idle version 6.0.0-beta.3 and using angular 6, this library is working fine system is on but timer stops when system goes to sleep mode. How to achieve idle state is system goes to sleep?

```
    import {Idle, DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES} from '@ng-idle/core';
    import {Keepalive} from '@ng-idle/keepalive';
    constructor(
    private idle: Idle, private keepalive: Keepalive) {

    // sets an idle timeout of 5 seconds, for testing purposes.
    idle.setIdle(900);
    // sets a timeout period of 5 seconds. after 10 seconds of 
    inactivity, the user will be considered timed out.
    idle.setTimeout(5);
    // sets the default interrupts, in this case, things like clicks, 
    scrolls, touches to the document
    idle.setInterrupts(DEFAULT_INTERRUPTSOURCES);

    idle.onIdleEnd.subscribe(() => {this.idleState = 'No longer idle.'
      console.log(this.idleState)
    });
    idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('loggedInTab') == 'true' || 
    localStorage.getItem('loggedInStatus') == 'true'){
    this.logoutService.logout().subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    localStorage.clear();
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
    });
    }
    this.idleState = 'Timed out!';
    this.timedOut = true;
    });
    idle.onIdleStart.subscribe(() => {this.idleState = 'You\'ve gone 
    idle!';
    console.log(this.idleState);
    });
    idle.onTimeoutWarning.subscribe((countdown) => this.idleState = 'You 
    will time out in ' + countdown + ' seconds!');

    // sets the ping interval to 15 seconds
    keepalive.interval(15);

    keepalive.onPing.subscribe(() => this.lastPing = new Date());

    this.reset();
    }

   reset() {
   this.idle.watch();
   this.idleState = 'Started.';
   this.timedOut = false;
   }

   ngOnDestroy() {
   this.idle.stop();
   }
```

I have used Ng Idle version 6.0.0-beta.3 and using angular 6, this library is working fine system is on but timer stops when system goes to sleep mode. How to achieve idle state is system goes to sleep?

Comment: you need to show code, need to explain what you have done and what is not working please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you setTimeout to false right before watch, then on windows it will logout the user right after computer gets back from sleep. Not working on Mac for me.

```
reset() {
   this.idle.setTimeout(false); //add this line
   this.idle.watch();
   this.idleState = 'Started.';
   this.timedOut = false;
}
```

https://github.com/moribvndvs/ng2-idle/issues/112